# How to normalize subtitles?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, media-player, subtitle, transcoding

I have developed a multimedia player based on ffmpeg framework. Now I adding support for subtitles. So instead of covering all the subtitle format on player side, I want to normalize and maintain single format in the streaming server. So, can anybody suggest me which is the best format for subtitles? I will convert all the incoming subtitle formats to the best format available? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [ASS/SSA](https://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/ssa.html) format is the most flexible, and SRT is the most common.

Comment: Thank you Mulvya. I am looking for any library or tool which can convert **CIP subtitle format to WebVTT**. Can you anyone help me to identify it. Thanks in advance.